# Unable to send email from GCP hosting

Tags: email, google-cloud-platform

I have created a hosting instance in GCP but unable to send or receive email from it. I have used Vesta-cp as control panel and Ubuntu 18.04 minimal as OS. I have opened all required ports in firewall rule and apply them to instance but still get nothing. Any one interested in this issue please answer. Thank You !

Comment: Edit your question with details. Which SMTP server are you using and how is it configured? If you are not hosting your own email server, which third party transport are you using? What port are you sending email on? What error messages are you getting? Your question as written cannot be answered. We can only guess on potential issues that you can look into.

Answer (score 1):

See this guide: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/ Port 25 is always blocked and can't be used to send emails.

[image]

Having said that, you probably are better off using managed service for sending emails. Managing security and compliance for mail servers are increasingly getting difficult to manage. So you are better off using a managed service to send emails.